# Parallel computing in python within recursion

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I am interested in parallelizing a `func()` of a python program, which frequently calls a `compute_heavy()` function. Noticeably, this parallelization should not be an implementation detail invisible from the outside. One way to parallelize is based on `multiprocessing` pools:

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def compute_heavy(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    return x*x

def func():
    with Pool(5) as p:
        result = p.map(compute_heavy, [1, 2, 3])
    return sum(result)
```

This essentially comes down to fork-join type parallelism.

However, my function is more complicated to evaluate, as illustrated by the example below:

```
def func(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    my_result = sum([compute_heavy(i) for i in range(x)])
    other_result = func(x - 1) # recursion!
    
    return my_result + other_result
```

First, it would probably be sensible to use a common pool throughout the program, which is easily remedied.

However, if I call `func(10)`, then its body has 10 parallelizable tasks, whereas the body of `func(1)` has just 1. Unfortunately, the `Pool.map` function blocks until all tasks are finished. So even with an unlimited number of processors, the call to `func(10)` will take 10 seconds, rather than 1, which I would prefer.

One approach would be to somehow include the recursive call to `func(x - 1)` into the argument to the `pool.map` function in order to wait only once. This could (?) however possibly cause a deadlock, since all processes in the pool are waiting for results (unless they return control to the pool during waiting?)

My question is: How can I achieve the optimal running time for the toy example without causing any type of resource exhaustion problems?

To this end I briefly looked into the `async` / `await` framework, which seems to be built around these principles, though it is apparently mostly used for I/O rather than computation, but maybe it works for computation as well?

Answer (score 1):

`asyncio` is well-suited for this !

you need to just launch tasks using `asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor` specifying the kind of executor to use (thread pool or process pool), and use `asynio.gather` on the futures on each step to ensure asyncio will await on them all at once instead of one at a time.

```py
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import time

global_pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()  
# or ThreadPoolExecutor depending on IPC overhead vs GIL overhead

def compute_heavy(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    return x*x

async def calc_sum(x):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    tasks = []
    for i in range(x):
        tasks.append(loop.run_in_executor(global_pool, compute_heavy, i))
    return sum(await asyncio.gather(*tasks))

async def func(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    my_result = calc_sum(x)
    other_result = func(x - 1) # recursion!
    final_result = sum(await asyncio.gather(my_result,other_result))
    return final_result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(asyncio.run(func(5)))
```

Comment: ProcessPoolExecutor will spawn new processes, though – depending on OP's data, it may not be transferable to those subprocesses, or the IPC may be very costly.

Comment: @AKX i agree, but "computationally heavy" usually means multiprocessing.

Comment: Not necessarily at all. It could mean heavy lifting being done in native code that can release the GIL, for one. But either way, just wanted to point out that there are drawbacks to using multiprocessing.

Comment: This has the slight problem of making `func` async, which I do not want. I take it I could move the `asyncio.run` into `func` itself?

Comment: @hfhc2 it would be doable for a `sum` aggregation, or any aggregate that can be accumulated, but if your function cannot be accumulated then you need it to be async.

Comment: Well, the problem to my mind is that the fork-join idea is now apparently missing its join, right? In order to not change the API I need to get from `async def ` land back to `def` somehow, even when returning a single value  or even `None`. That should be possible, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Without resorting to `asyncio`, you can do this with multiprocessing in similar fashion. Instead of `Pool.map` you can submit tasks without blocking using [`map_async`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map_async), and then get result later when it is needed.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def compute_heavy(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    return x*x

def func(x, pool):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    range_res = pool.map_async(compute_heavy, range(x))
    other_res = func(x - 1, pool)
    return sum(range_res.get()) + other_res

with Pool(100) as pool:  # 100 processes to allow submitting everything at once
    func(10, pool)
```

On my system `time python test_mp.py` gives

```
real    0m1.391s
user    0m0.354s
sys     0m0.365s
```